# Div with backgroun color within Div with pre-determined width

Tags: html, css

I feel like I should be able to figure this out but I really can't...

I basically have a div that is contains another set of divs/elements. I want the first div within this container to have a background color to effectively give the parent div a colored top bar/portion. The closest I can get is using display: flex; to give it full height coloring, but I can't get it the way I want. Any help is appreciated.

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.content {
  height: 400px;
}

.sp-h3 {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #008ed0;
  color: white;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container::before,
.container::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sp-h3">
    <h3>Bob McBob</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Just for something</P>
    <ul>
      <li>The number 1</li>
      <li>The number 2</li>
      <li>The number 3</li>
      <li>The number 4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the edit with improved formatting and snippet :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set `padding` to the child elements, instead of setting it to the whole `.container`.

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 4px;
  
}

.content {
  height: 400px;
  padding: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.sp-h3 {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #008ed0;
  color: white;
  padding: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container::before,
.container::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sp-h3">
    <h3>Bob McBob</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Just for something</P>
    <ul>
      <li>The number 1</li>
      <li>The number 2</li>
      <li>The number 3</li>
      <li>The number 4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for a rookie mistake on my part. Apologies and thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You can consider a simple gradient coloration on the container so you won't have the issue related to padding:

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(to bottom,#008ed0 60px,transparent 0);
}

.content {
  height: 400px;
}

.sp-h3 {
  display: flex;
  color: white;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container::before,
.container::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sp-h3">
    <h3>Bob McBob</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Just for something</p>
    <ul>
      <li>The number 1</li>
      <li>The number 2</li>
      <li>The number 3</li>
      <li>The number 4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```